# Accessing URL in 'get' method of view

Tags: django, url, view

I want a web page (with the url `page3`) to be displayed differently depending on whether a user on my website is redirected to it from the pages with urls `page1` or `page2`.

How can I access the full url (not just the query parametres in it) from which the user was redirected in the `get` method  in the view associated with the url `page3` ?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/request-response/#attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the docs more thoroughly (thanks for the tip Brandon!), I found `request.META['HTTP_REFERER']` did the trick.